# How to call several Oracle stored procedures in Pentaho (PDI)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, pentaho, kettle

I have the next script which I'm trying to run as Job/Transformation in Pentaho Data-Integration - it is taken from Toad where it works as expected.

```
begin
 SOME_PACKAGE.SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE;
 SOME_PACKAGE2.SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE2;
end;
/
```

I tried with two steps Call DB Procedure(one after another), but it doesn't behave in the same way - the first procedure is setting some params and the second is trying to use them, but with two steps - the params for the second one are not set.

I tried with the step Execute SQL script, but it seems I cannot figure out how to call these procedures from there.
The first procedure has one optional parameter, the second doesn't

I tried with

```
begin
 SOME_PACKAGE.SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE;
 SOME_PACKAGE2.SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE2;
end;
```

(get ORA-06550: line 2, column 32: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file")

Or

```
SOME_PACKAGE.SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE;
SOME_PACKAGE2.SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE2;
```

(get ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement)

Or

```
 CALL SOME_PACKAGE.SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE;
 CALL SOME_PACKAGE2.SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE2;
```

get(ORA-00911: invalid character)

Or

```
EXEC SOME_PACKAGE.SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE;
EXEC SOME_PACKAGE2.SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE2;
```

(get ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement)

Or the same but adding the schema prefix - the same result.

Comment: Have you checked `Execute for each row?` checkbox In the first option you've tried (in `Execute SQL script`)?

Comment: have you considered writing a wrapper procedure that calls the first and second procedures?  From Pentaho this would be considered one transaction

Comment: i checked `Execute for each row` but doesn't help.
The thing is that I have 20 different cases for `SOMESTOREDPROCEDURE2` and I don't think writing a wrapper for all of them will be a good idea. I think i will try a new approach to the problem. Anyway it sounds strange that in the `Execute SQL script` you cannot write everything.

Comment: Sorry I confused the checkbox, you had to check `Execute as a single statement` checkbox in `Execute SQL script`. It should work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In PDI all the steps are executed in **parallel**. So if you call 2 or more **DB Procedure** steps, it will be executed in parallel. As per your question, this is not you intend to achieve. The only way to achieve is to add two separate tranformations(.ktr) files and call in each of them "DB Procedure" steps.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried it in this way - having a Job with two transformations and everyone of them was calling one DB procedure, but the result was that again, when it comes to the second stored procedure, it see the parameters unchanged. Is it not possible this to be done via **Execute SQL Script** step?